# how to display xml node using xsl?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have problem with this XML file, please help.

how can i display the content node in html with xsl

**XML:**

```
<site>
   <page>
 <content><P align="center"><FONT size="2" face="Tahoma"><IMG        src="http://www.alkul.co.il/online/2011/1/10/9/untitled.bmp"></FONT></P>
 </content>
   </page>
</site>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
<xsl:value-of select="site/page/content"/>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What do I need to change in the XSL file? 
Which tags do I need to use?

Which tags do I need to use?

Comment: you can search on google.There are many tuts available

Comment: "*What do I need to change in the XSL file?*" Nothing. The problem is with your XML file. It is not well-formed **and** the content node has no value to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a problem with your XML, as it is not well-formed, and XSLT can only work on well-formed documents. In particular, your **img** tag is not closed.

Now... If it did look like this...

```
<site>
   <page>
  <content>
   <P align="center">
     <FONT size="2" face="Tahoma">
       <IMG src="http://www.alkul.co.il/online/2011/1/10/9/untitled.bmp" />
     </FONT>
   </P>
  </content>
   </page>
</site>
```

Then the command you are looking for here is **xsl:copy-of**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:copy-of select="site/page/content/*"/>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of `/*` as you don't want to copy the **content** element, only its children.

Comment: "*Note the use of `/*`*" What's the difference - it's still empty, isn't it?

Comment: No, it isn't. It has an **P** child node, which in turn has **IMG** element in it.